# sharing a drive same user different UID on two computers

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, ext4

I've got an extra drive that I created an ext4 partition when it was connected to one machine. I plugged it into another machine and now I no longer have access to my files from that machine because my UID on the second machine is not the same as on the first machine.  I would like to be able to plug the drive into either machine and be able to access the same files as the same user (name).

Obviously I could change my UID on the second machine, but then I would have to recursively find all files owned by me and change the owner which could take a long time to complete.   Previously the drive was NTFS and I reformatted, but at that time I mounted with an option specifying the UID that owned the files, but obviously ext4 has actual the permissions expected by Linux on a per file basis so this would mess things up if any other users had files on the device.

Is there some better way that I can proceed so I can access my files from both machines?

Answer (score 1):

`bindfs` is the utility you are looking for.

See https://bindfs.org and https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html.

You'll be able to "map" a new UID to an old one with something like this:

`sudo bindfs --map=1000/1400:@1000/@1400 /path/to/drive  /path/to/drive`

where `1000` is the from-uid, `1400` is the to-uid, `@1000` is the from-gid, and `@1400` is the to-gid.

Yes, that's right: you can use the same path in both arguments... and it will "mount" the new (mapped) partition right over the old.

Comment: I had to use the `--no-allow-other` option too. This stops `bindfs` from asking for permissions that my OS (Ubuntu 22.04) doesn't grant by default.